# Infix to Postfix using Stacks w/ Professor's Algorithm

Tags: c++, stack

Been scratching my head for hours already and I have no clue what my mistake is. I'm following my professor's derived algorithm step by step and I don't know why it isn't working properly.

Here's the derived Algorithm:[image]

Here's the code that I tried to make:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "ecpe202.h"
#define Max 100

using namespace std;

int getICP(char x){
    if (x == ')'){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x == '^'){
        return 4;
    }
    else if (x == '*' || x == '/'){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (x == '+' || x == '-'){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (x == '('){
        return 4;
    }
}

int getISP(char x){
    if (x == ')'){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (x == '^'){
        return 3;
    }
    else if (x == '*' || x == '/'){
        return 2;
    }
    else if (x == '+' || x == '-'){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (x == '('){
        return 0;
    }
}

bool isOperator(char ch){
    if (ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '^' || ch == '*' || ch == '(' || ch == ')'){
        return (true);
    }
    else{
        return (false);
    }
}

int main(){
    char infix[Max];
    char ch;
    int length;
    myQueue que;
    myStack stk;
    createQ(que);
    createS(stk);

    cout << "Enter an infix Expression: ";
    cin >> infix;
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "The postfix Expression: ";

    length = strlen(infix);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        addQ(que, infix[i]);
    }

    while (!isEmptyQ(que)){
        ch = retrieveQ(que);

        //start of infix to postfix algo
        //1. push
        if (ch == '('){
            pushS(stk, ch);
        }
        //2. if scanned is operand
        if (!isOperator(ch)){
            cout << ch;
        }
        else{
            //2.1 push if...
            if (isEmptyS(stk) || getICP(ch) > getISP(topS(stk)) || topS(stk) == '('){
                pushS(stk, ch);
            }
            //2.2. pop all operators
            else{
                while(!isEmptyS(stk) && getISP(topS(stk)) >= getICP(ch) || topS(stk) == '('){
                    cout << popS(stk);
                }
            }
            pushS(stk, ch);
        }
        //3. If scanned ')'
        bool loop = true;
        if (ch == ')'){
            do{
                if (ch == '('){
                    loop = false;
                }
                else{
                    cout << popS(stk);
                }
            }while(loop == true);
        }
        //repeat 1-3
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

For the ecpe202.h:

```cpp
#include<dos.h>
#include<windows.h>

#define FOREVER true
#define MAXSTACK 100
#define MAXQUEUE 100

using namespace std;


struct myStack{
    int tos;
    char s[MAXSTACK];
};

struct myQueue{
    int head, tail, q[MAXQUEUE];
};

//STACK
void createS(myStack &S){
    S.tos=-1;
}

void pushS(myStack &S, char item){
    S.s[++S.tos] = item;
}

char popS(myStack &S){
    return(S.s[S.tos--]);
}

char topS(myStack S){
    return (S.s[S.tos]);
}

bool isFullS(myStack S){
    if(S.tos == MAXSTACK - 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool isEmptyS(myStack S){
    if (S.tos == -1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

//QUEUE
void createQ(myQueue &Q){
    Q.head = 0;
    Q.tail = 0;
}

void addQ(myQueue &Q, char item){
    Q.q[Q.tail++] = item;
    Q.tail %= MAXQUEUE;
}

char retrieveQ(myQueue &Q){
    char temp;
    temp = Q.q[Q.head++];
    Q.head %= MAXQUEUE;
    return temp;
}

bool isFullQ(myQueue Q){
    if (Q.tail == MAXQUEUE)
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool isEmptyQ(myQueue Q){
    if (Q.tail == Q.head)
        return true;
    return false;
}

//GOTOXY
void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void clrscr(){
    system("CLS");
}
```

The output that my code:[image]

What seems to be wrong in my program? tried re-reading it a couple of times and I still can't fix it.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Did you try the debugger and stepping through ? Please post the queue and stack content as you go, and check whether their content make sense.

Comment: You have placed a `pushS(stk, ch);` outside of point 2.2 that should be inside it. (There may be more problems, so I'm not posting that as an answer.)

Comment: Please include the text, not a picture of it. A picture makes it difficult to read on many screens and prevents people from searching in it copying it to work on a solution.

Comment: @NathanOliver Oh, thanks for that. Haven't tried that yet. Im quite fresh to programming my self so there are still a lot of things that i'm not aware yet

Comment: @Dragonthoughts sorry about that, i tried pasting it through words but idk how to format it well yet and ended up breaking some of the indentions and spacing, so i went for an image instead. My bad

Comment: In addition to the error pointed out by @molbdnilo, you also need to add code at the end that will empty the operator stack. Also, you might check your conditional @2.2. I don't think you want to pop `(` operators there.